# Changing element style on sibling hover with CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, css-selectors

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="e1">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <div id="main">text text text text</div>
  <div id="footer">something</div>
</div>
```

And I want the `<h1>` to turn blue for example when the footer is hovered. I know I can do it with Javascript but I was wondering If you might know some CSS trick to do it without.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about CSS3, but in standard CSS, you cannot do that unless the header were a child element of the footer.

Comment: With pure CSS, I don't believe this is possible, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Justin Satyr: CSS3 selectors can be considered "standard CSS" now, as that module was standardized as a W3C Recommendation a few months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `h1` comes before `#footer`, so it's not possible with pure CSS as it doesn't provide a selector to match the preceding sibling element.

Comment: You r probably right. The closest I got to a solution was with: http://jsfiddle.net/bVPqx/1/. But switching the div and h1 roles in the selector doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by switching their roles in the selector?

Comment: using "#e h1:hover~#footer" will work but using "#e #footer:hover~h1" will not: http://jsfiddle.net/bVPqx/3/

Answer (score 0):

```css
#e1:hover {
      color:red;
}

#main, #footer{
    color:black 
}
```

Another option.

Answer (score -1):

**I've implemented it in a way, not changing html structure, and pure CSS.**

see it in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ijse/dhcqw/